# Change excel background colour on specific text entry

Tags: vba, excel

Heading may be a bit misleading, so here goes..

In a spreadsheet I need to monitor Col "I" to test if the number inserted there contains "22822".. it normally is a number like 22822564 or 22722762. these numbers mean something so if 22822xxx is entered the cell just left (in Col "H" has to change and display a yellow background and the Text "Waiting on Processing"

Once the set is processed the user will manually change this value to "Processed" and then the background col has to change back to nothing...

Thus.. User enters 22822564 in I33, then H33 will display "Waiting on Processing" with a yellow background. If the content of H33 is manually changed then remove the background colour.

I have so far done this and am stuck..

1. the find.. does not seem to work, most probably because i did not tell it to find a part but an exact match, don´t know how to.. hitting a blank here
2. don´t seem to be able to change the col "H" even with an exact match
3. have not even gotten as far as the part where a manual entry is made into "Hx"

Any helpers ?

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim WatchRange As Range
   Dim IntersectRange As Range
   Dim FillRange As Range
   Dim IntersectFillRange As Range
   Set WatchRange = Range("I1:I1110")
   Set FillRange = Range("H1:H1110")
   Set IntersectRange = Intersect(Target, WatchRange)
   Set IntersectFillRange = Intersect(FillRange, WatchRange)
   If IntersectRange Is Nothing Then
    'Do Nothing
   Else
    On Error Resume Next
    check = Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("22822", IntersectRange)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If check = False Then
        MsgBox "String does not contain 22822"
    Else:
        MsgBox "Found it !!!"
        IntersectFillRange.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 160, 35)
    End If


   End If
   End Sub
```

Comment: Is `22822` always the first five digits or could it appear anywhere in a number e.g. `XX22822XX`?

Comment: yup, indeed it is, always starts with 22822xxx

Comment: This code works for me up until `IntersectFillRange.Interior.Color`, which is (and can only be) `Nothing` based on the arguments you've provided.

Comment: Yup, same on this end, but just could not figure out how to carry on from there. Alex has provided a much leaner and meaner solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim WatchRange As Range
    Set WatchRange = Range("I1:I1110")

    If Not Intersect(Target, WatchRange) Is Nothing Then
        If VBA.Left$(Target, 5) = "22822" Then
            Target.Offset(0, -1) = "Waiting on Processing"
            Target.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 160, 35)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to remove the color formatting if somebody overwrites `"Waiting on Processing"` with `"Processed"` then I'd simply set a conditional format on `H1:H1110` which sets the background color to white if the cell value equals `"Processed"`

Comment: WOW... sooo easy. Brilliant. Learned a few things from this. Very nice. Thank you.

Comment: Alex.. is there a way to specify a Range in the "Target.Offset(0, -1)" section ? Would like to use that all cells from col "A:I" get a colour change ?

Comment: managed to change the entire row colour. now working on only a few col.    Rows(Target.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(220, 90, 160)

Comment: @Haissam try something like `Range(Target).Resize(1,3).Interior.Color.RGB(220,90,160)`. That should color three columns in target row, starting with the target cell.

Comment: @David, nope Sir.. not working. `Range(Target).Resize(1, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 64, 64)` managed to do the entire line, which is ok but a few col would be nicer looking. `Rows(Target.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 64, 64)`

Comment: Try this: `Range("A" & Target.Row & ":I" & Target.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 160, 35)`

Comment: @Alex.. YOU'RE A GENIUS... learnt something new again. Thank you.

Comment: Oops my code should've said this instead: `Range(Target.Address).Resize(1,3).Interior.Color = RGB(255,64, 64)` should work. But it looks like @AlexP gave you another solution.  Cheers.

Comment: @Haissam: Haha. I wish I was a genius at this type of stuff - some people on this site are so far ahead of me I need a telescope to see them! Glad you are learning and you've made progress.